# LaTeX in Plotly/Jupyter not working on Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, plotly, jupyter

I would like to have LaTeX-formatted axis labels in my plotly figures in Jupyter notebooks, but they are nowhere to be seen on Firefox. When I run them in Chromium they show up fine.

Also, when I look at the [official Plotly page for LaTeX](https://plotly.com/python/LaTeX/) the examples are not rendered properly on Firefox for me: axis labels aren't rendered and the figure layout is all messed up. Again Chromium is fine.

Example code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,101)
y = np.sin(x)
fig = px.line(x=x, y=y)
fig.update_xaxes(title=r'$t/\sqrt(3)$')

fig.show()
```

Versions:

```
plotly==5.1.0
firefox==93.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: It seems to be a bug in firefox as shown [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5374).